# Scroll is auto scrolling only to half of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

Friends I'm doing a chat module ih PHP for that I require a Div containing the conversation between the user , Using the jquery I tried to bring the scroll to the bottom of the div but it works only wen the content in the div is low , when it crosses certain limit the scroll stands scrolling on the mid way , I have attached the fiddle of working example here ,

http://jsfiddle.net/jPVAf/50/

if u copy paste the following lines

```
<p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p>
<p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p>
<p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p>
<p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p>
<p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p>
```

about 600 - 700 lines the scroll will stop in the midway but my requirement is it should scroll even though there is 1000 of records with in it .

Comment: 'fiddle of WORKING example': so what's the problem then? :)

Comment: @Arg0n : if u copy paste the above content  <p>alskdjg;j ;jhe ;he fkh</p> about 1000 lines it stops scrolling on the half way .

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your javascript with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jPVAf/987/):

```
$('div').animate({scrollTop: $('div')[0].scrollHeight});
```

Comment: If I use this code i got reverse response it went to the top of the div instead scrolling to the bottom . 

$('.chat_history').animate({scrollTop: $('.chat_history')[0].scrollHeight});